# libimobiledevice4, unmet dependencies and ErrorBrokenCount>0

Tags: dependencies

I have done something stupid and can't undo it.

I tried installing libimobiledevice4 by doing:

```
sudo dpkg -i libimobiledevice4_1.1.6-git20140105_amd64.deb
```

I did so following instructions from a website that I now can't find.

I now have an error listed on my top panel, telling me `ErrorBrokenCount>0`

libimobiledevice4 has unmet dependencies:

```
Depends: libtasn1-3 (>= 2.14-0) but it is not installable synaptic :
Depends: libept1.4.12 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: rarian-compat but it is not going to be installed E: Unmet dependencies.
```

If i try `apt-get -f install`, i get:

```
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. 
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

If i try `apt-get remove libimobiledevice4`, i get:

```
gvfs-backends : Depends: libimobiledevice4 (>= 1.1.5) but it is not going to be installed
 libgpod-common : Depends: libimobiledevice4 (>= 0.9.7) but it is not going to be installed
 libgpod4 : Depends: libimobiledevice4 (>= 0.9.7) but it is not going to be installed
 upower : Depends: libimobiledevice4 (>= 0.9.7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Does anyone have any ideas how i can undo what i did with: `sudo dpkg -i libimobiledevice4_1.1.6-git20140105_amd64.deb`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this with:

sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends libimobiledevice4

Then I ran

sudo apt-get install -f

And libimobiledevice4 installed from the repos.

All seems to be working now.

Thanks to bapoumba: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2234500